# What is the difference between a class and a interface someone explain please?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

```
        //**@Controller**
//@DTO like this way it does not work but when i change do interface it does why,?***
      @Post()
      @UsePipes(new JoiValidationPipe(createCatSchema))
      public createCats(@Body() createCats: CreateCatDto) {
        console.log("cat props are-----", createCats);
        return `  message `
      }
    
    
    // **@ValidationPipe**
    @Injectable()
    export class JoiValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
        constructor(private schema: ObjectSchema) { }
    
        transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
            const {error} = this.schema.validate(value);
            if (error) {
                throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
    
    export class CreateCatDto {
        name: string;
        age: number;
        breed: string;
    }
    
    export interface CreateCatDto {
        name: string;
        age: number;
        breed: string;
    }
```

**why after replace class with interface it work i dont understand it very well **
**it will work with class if i add class-validator**
**thank you in advice**